# SCSS: How to use two classes together with an ampersand?

Tags: sass, nested, ampersand

I have some css rules to be applied for primary button, I did something like this:

```
.my-btn {
  &--primary {
     padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

Now I want same rules to be applied for a primary button with "sm" class, I can do something like this:

```
.my-btn {
  &--primary, &--primary.my-btn--sm  {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

This is working for me. But I want to use "&" for "sm" as well, like this:

```
.my-btn {
  &--primary, &--primary.&--sm  {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this case, a solution could be use a variable:

```
.my-btn {
  $this: &;
  &--primary, &--primary#{$this}--sm  {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

Or use interpolation syntax

```
.my-btn {
  &--primary, &--primary#{&}--sm  {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```